# Generating data for the run of all possible paths in the program

Tags: c++, z3

I'm new to Z3 and searched for the answer to my question here and on Google. I was not successful.

This is the code producing the problem:

```
void test(string str) {
    if (str [0] == 'g') {
        cout << "\"The first letter g" case"<< endl;
        if (str [1] == 'a') cout << "Second letter is 'a'";
        else cout << "Second letter is not 'a'";
    } else {
        cout << "The non-g case" << endl;
        if (str [1] == 'b') cout << "Second letter is 'b'";
        else cout << "Second letter is not 'b'";
    }
}
```

I need to automatically generate the input data so that the code was run all the way.
Is it possible to do so at all with z3? If so, how can I do this using the z3 C/C++API?

Comment: Do you really need z3 for something as simple as this?

Comment: The actual problem with this question is that you do not describe the **output** you want to achieve. Please be clear what your inputs and expected outputs are. What does it mean when you say 'generate the input data so that the code was run all the way'?

Comment: Oh, it's my fault, @NathanielFord, sorry.  I want to get at each iteration of a new input string that led the program to a new execute path . And initial condition - an arbitrary string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly answering your question, but SAT/SMT solvers have been used before to generate such "exploit" vectors with considerable success. For instance, check out Brumley's AEG system: http://security.ece.cmu.edu/aeg/index.html, amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

[Z3](http://z3.codeplex.com) is not a test-case generator or fuzzer, it is a theorem prover. However, Z3 is used to implement fuzzers and test-case generators. One of them is [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/), a white box unit testing for .NET.
Z3 is also used in [Sage](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/peli/automated-whitebox-fuzz-testing-with-sage) a white box fuzzer for x86 binaries. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any test-case generator for C++ based on Z3.